# unordered_map usage

Tags: c++

```
class CTime
{
public:    
    CTime(){}

    class valueComp   
    {
    public:
        bool operator()(const tm &A,const tm &B) const {
            if ((A.tm_mday < B.tm_mday) && (A.tm_mon< B.tm_mon)&& (A.tm_year < B.tm_year) &&      
                (A.tm_hour< B.tm_hour)&&   (A.tm_min< B.tm_min) &&  (A.tm_sec< B.tm_sec))

               return true;

           return false;
        }
    };

    time_t  MakeTime(struct tm *trf) {
        if(HashTime.size()>86400)
            HashTime.clear();

        it =HashTime.find(*trf);
        if( it   == HashTime.end())
        {   m_tDateSeconds= mktime (trf);    
            cout<<"mktime calculated"<<endl;    
            HashTime[*trf]= m_tDateSeconds;    
            return m_tDateSeconds;                                                    
        }
       else
       {     cout<<"retrieving from map";
             HashTime.find(*trf) ;
       }}
private:
    std::tr1::unordered_map<struct tm,long int,valueComp> HashTime;
    std::tr1::unordered_map<struct tm,long int,valueComp>::iterator it;
    time_t         m_tDateSeconds;
};

int main()
{return 0;
}
```

this is what i've coded inorder to check whether unordered map is working for me or not ?

if there is any error in code please let me know as i am a beginner.

Comment: however this works :
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <tr1/unordered_map>
    typedef std::tr1::unordered_map<std::string, int> AgeTable;

    int main() {

    AgeTable ages;

    ages.insert( std::make_pair( "Joe", 25 ) );
    
    ages.insert( std::make_pair( "Sally", 18 ) );
    
    ages.insert( std::make_pair( "Billy", 11 ) );

    AgeTable::iterator iter;
    
    for ( iter = ages.begin(); iter != ages.end(); iter++ ) {
    
    std::cout << iter->first << " is " << iter->second << std::endl;
    }

Comment: please **edit** that into the question. In the comments section that is pretty unreadable. You may also want to look at the [Editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to properly format code in your posts. I already made an effort to format the one you posted before for you.

Comment: Why are you using an unordered map in the first place? Do you know what it’s doing and how it differs from the ordinary (ordered) map? Your code doesn’t look like you do.

Comment: Is this a request for a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), or do you have an actual problem or error? I really can't tell from the question.

Comment: Yes its a kind of code review..actually i wrote the same code with std::map but its taking lot of time in data retrieval and insertion so i replaced std::map with unordered_map..Have i done it wrong? Please suggest me some changes.

Answer (score 0):

`unordered_map` is a hash table, so as well as a test for equality, you need to supply a hash function. The standard library will provide a hash function for the builtin types and a few others like `std::string`, which is used in the case of `unordered_map<std::string,int>`, but there won't be one for `struct tm`, so you'll have to write one. This must be provided as the third template parameter --- the equality test is the fourth parameter, so you need `unordered_map<struct tm,long,myHash,valueComp>`.

The hash function must be a callable object type, where the function call operator takes a value of the key type and returns a `size_t`:

```
struct myHash{
    size_t operator()(struct tm const&);
};
```

It's probably easier to just use a `std::map<struct tm,long,compareTm>` (and write the ordering comparison `compareTm`) rather than use an `unordered_map` and come up with a good hash function.

Comment: Thanks alot for your guidance but in my case what do you think that unordered_map will help if we are passing key as a structure ?

Comment: You can use structures as keys in a `map` or `unordered_map`. You just need to write the appropriate support functions --- hash and equality for `unordered_map`, an ordering comparison for `map`. `unordered_map` can have faster lookup if the has function is a good fit, and is fast. If the hash function is slow and/or poor then `unordered_map` can be much slower than `map`.